# Failed to run custom build command for qmlrs

Tags: qt, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use the qmlrs Rust bindings to Qt, but I cannot compile. I've installed all dependencies.

- Rust 1.9.0
- Cargo 0.10.0-nightly (10ddd7d 2016-04-08)

Cargo build log:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `qmlrs v0.1.1`

Process didn't exit successfully: `/home/pedro/Documents/repositories
/rust-sample/target/debug/build/qmlrs-e7d90e9b9c603e6f/build-script-
build` (exit code: 101)

--- stdout

cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=qmlrswrapper

cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=stdc++

cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/home/pedro/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-
88ac128001ac3a9a/qmlrs-0.1.1/ext/libqmlrswrapper/build


--- stderr

thread '<main>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: 
"`\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Qml 
Qt5Quick\"` did not exit successfully: exit code: 1\n--- stdout\nPackage 
Qt5Qml was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should 
add the directory containing `Qt5Qml.pc\'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH 
environment variable\nNo package \'Qt5Qml\' found\nPackage Qt5Quick was 
not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the 
directory containing `Qt5Quick.pc\'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment 
variable\nNo package \'Qt5Quick\' found\n"', ../src/libcore/result.rs:746

note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Comment: Did you install Qt on your system? The `qmlrs` crate is just a binding, the library still needs to be installed.

Comment: Did you follow the directions in the error message? *Perhaps you should add ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install a Qt's `-dev` package that provides the file. [Here's a hint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/374755/what-package-do-i-need-to-build-a-qt-5-cmake-application/724308#724308) how you can find relevant package using apt-file (in case you are using Debian-derived distribution).
In your case the error message says
`Perhaps you should add the directory containing Qt5Qml.pc`, so:

```
$ sudo apt install apt-file && sudo apt update
$ apt-file search Qt5Qml.pc
>>> qtdeclarative5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/Qt5Qml.pc
$ sudo apt install qtdeclarative5-dev
```